# What command can I run to open a remote folder in GUI using an identity key?

Tags: linux, sftp, nautilus

I recently used the `nautilus` file manager to open up remote folders hosted on my Linux VPS.

Each time I want to access them, I need to manually connect to my server through GUI.

I was wondering if there was a command that could directly open the remote folders in the Nautilus file manager using an identity key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I realized that `sftp` and `ssh` used the same identity key.

I generated a new key and added it to the ssh agent, refer to https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent for more information.

I used `nautilus sftp://user@host/path/` to solve the problem. Note that no `:` is needed between the host and path parameters.